# Help! Why do blocked bots still waste bandwidth?

Tags: linux, security, hosting, .htaccess, web-hosting

I've blocked a majority of bots that keep **sending** POST requests to my website, using .htaccess.

Each time one of these bots tries to access my website it receives a 403 forbidden error message.

My question is, why is my bandwidth usage still increasing if I've blocked them in my .htaccess file?

I was always under the impression that web hosting bandwidth is measured by the amount of data that my server sends, not by the amount that it receives.

Is there a way to configure my .htaccess file to just ignore these bots and not send back a status code?

By the way, I'm using a shared server with "unlimited" bandwidth, but the amount of bandwidth that these bots are wasting is rediculous.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .htaccess files tells your server what specific reply should be sent to these bots. So the request is still happening, and you are still sending back data (the 403 message).

You have no way to prevent the botnet request to reach you, only your provider can block it before it reaches your server. However, you can send nothing back by simply closing the connection for this IP. I'm not sure if Apache has a module to do that, otherwise you can use a software firewall like iptables to do that.

Answer (score 5):

By the time your `.htaccess` file takes effect, the client's payload has already passed the network interface of your server. From the point of view of your ISP there is basically no difference in in- or outgoing traffic from your server. You or your provider will have to pay it anyway.

If you don't want any data transfer happen, you'll need to block the clients in the border router of your ISP (or at least in a packet filter which is *not* running on the server itself).

Answer (score 2):

As per the other answers, once the bot gets to the stage of getting a 403 response back, you have both sent and received data.

It'd probably be better to not respond at all, if you can find an apache module to simply drop the connection.

If you have control of the host AND use SYN cookies, it may be worth to also route all IPs you block to 127.0.0.1 (or, maybe even better, add them to a DROP rule in an iptables chain).

Comment: extending Vatine's answer, you could setup Squid ( or something similar ) and setup acls

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take. One is setting up firewall rules via iptables. Second is disallowing these bots on robot.txt

Comment: `robots.txt` is purely *advisory* - any robot that wants to ignore it, can.